# Callback not working in JavaScript node app for making Sync behavior

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I'm trying to run this code with node but it's not working properly:

```
var request = require('request');

function firstandSecond(callback){
    request('http://demo3691077.mockable.io/aman', function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log("first");
        }
    })
    request('http://demo3691077.mockable.io/aman', function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log("second");
        }
    })

    callback();
}

function third(){
    console.log("third");
}

function myfunc(){
    firstandSecond(third);
}

myfunc();
```

After running this My output is like:

third
second
first

but I want 'third' to be printed at last every time I run the code. Here both 'first' and 'second' rest call are happening in a parallel way. Am I doing something wrong with the callback ? Please explain how to do this type of functionality or is there any better way to achieve these kind of functionalities?

Comment: Move your callback(); inside if after  console.log("first");

Comment: `request` is **asynchronous**. That's why you have to pass a callback to it. The callback is called when the request is done. Therefore you have to call your own `callback` in that callback.

Comment: I have edited the code what if I have two async calls then?

Comment: Look into promises and `Promise.all`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since request call is asynchronous, it may be executed later due to network latency.

So, in order 'execute them in parallel' you may use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). I use quotation mark because although it may seem that it is executing the async calls in parallel it is still one after the other under the hood.

Also there will be cases when 'second' comes before 'first', because Promise.all evaluates promises that are resolved first, which could be the case for 'second'.

```js
var request = require('request')

function makeRequest(url, order) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request(url, (error, response, body) => {
      if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        console.log(order);
        return resolve();
     }
    });
  });
}

function firstandSecond(callback) {
  const promiseArr = [makeRequest('http://demo3691077.mockable.io/aman', 'first'), makeRequest('http://demo3691077.mockable.io/aman', 'second')];
  return Promise.all(promiseArr).then(callback);
}

function third(){
  console.log("third");
}

firstandSecond(third);
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer but I have edited the code what if I have 2 async calls then I want to print third at last everytime i run the code

Comment: I want both async calls to happen in a parallel way like not 1 after the other, In your answer second rest call will start only after getting first's reponse. I want first and second parallel and third printing after I get responses from both first and second

Comment: @AmanDeepSharma perhaps like what I've done in my updated answer? 'parallel' async calls and then calls the callback afterwards.

Comment: Did you run this code? It looks it should really work but When I'm running it ...It is printing only 'first' and 'second' :( :( . If you can run it once please ...by providing request import " var request = require('request'); ". Let me know if it is working fine for you

Comment: @AmanDeepSharma I've updated my code again and i've tested it. Lemme know if this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve exactly what you want by using the parallel function in the async module. Try this...

```
 var async=require("async");
 var request=require("request");

firstandSecond(callback){
 async.parallel([
   function(cb){
     request('http://demo3691077.mockable.io/aman', function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
           console.log("first");
           cb(null,'first');
        }
        else{
           cb(error);
        }

   });
  },
   function(cb){
     request('http://demo3691077.mockable.io/aman', function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
           console.log("second");
           cb(null,'second');
        }
        else{
           cb(error);
        }
    });
   }
 ],function(err,result){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        else{
            callback();
        }
 });

 }

function third(){
     console.log("third");
}

function myfunc(){
    firstandSecond(third);
}

myfunc();
```

Async module is one of the most useful modules in node. Read more about the parallel function here https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#parallel